# argparse - Why the code is executed without being called?

Tags: python, class, arguments, argparse

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how python argparse works.

My script has three positional arguments that don't take parameters: make, compile and clean. I've done it through subparsers like the documentation says, but my code keeps running without arguments or even with arguments it doesn't call the right function (it runs Language().make() in every case).

My argparse code:

```
lang = Language()
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='e-cidadania language catalog generator.')
subparser = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_make = subparser.add_parser('make', help='Create all the language' \
                                                ' catalogs for translation,'\
                                                ' including JavaScript.')
parser_make.set_defaults(func=lang.make())

parser_compile = subparser.add_parser('compile', help='Compile all the language' \
                                                      ' catalogs for use.')
parser_compile.set_defaults(func=lang.compile())

parser_clean = subparser.add_parser('clean', help='Delete all the language catalogs.' \
                                                  ' After this you will'\
                                                  ' have to rebuild the catalogs' \
                                                  ' and translate them.')
parser_clean.set_defaults(func=lang.clean())


args = parser.parse_args()
```

The first line calls the only class in the file, called `Language` with three main methods, `make`, `clean` and `compile` and other private methods, `_iterator` and `__init__`.

**Update** The complete script is here: http://dpaste.com/hold/681317/

What I am missing from the documentation to run this?

Comment: If your goal is handling simple positional arguments, I recommend you take a look into either of these argparse wrappers: http://plac.googlecode.com/hg/doc/plac.html http://packages.python.org/argh/reference.html

Comment: +1, didn't know about them :)

Comment: We're all here to help each other :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're calling `make` yourself, here:

```
parser_make.set_defaults(func=lang.make())
```

In particullar, this part:

```
lang.make()
```

As a result, the `func` arg is set to the return value of `make`.

Instead, you probably want to pass the method as argument, without calling it:

```
parser_make.set_defaults(func=lang.make)
```

**Update**

Note that `argparse` will not call the methods for you. It will return them in the `func` attribute of the `args` object returned by the parser.

So after you parse the args, you have to call it yourself:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args.func()
```

Here `args.func` will be one of the method objects (`lang.make`, `lang.compile` or `lang.clean` depending on which command was specified as script argument). Applying the call operator `()` to it will execute it.

Comment: That way when I execute the script it doesn't return anything. You can see the complete script here: http://dpaste.com/hold/681317/

Comment: \*piano falls upon oscar\* I didn't realize that just calling func() would be enough. Thanks